# How can I output the date of the last "day"?

Tags: bash, date, terminal

I want to print the day of the last Monday for example
using the `date` command in a terminal
Provided I do not know what day/ date is today but I can use date to find out the date and then use it to find out what date the first previous monday was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gnu date, you can try the following command:

```
date -d "last monday"
```

Comment: I get it, but "Are you kidding?" may not be the best way to start an explanation...

Comment: The answer was below 30 characters.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer, that only applies to GNU `date` please mention that too.